# How to run `corepack enable` to install Yarn berry?

Tags: nix, nix-shell

For modern versions of Yarn, aka Yarn Berry, the preferred installation is through Corepack, and Corepack is included by default with Node.js installs (>=16.10). See https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install

This is what I've tried to do `corepack enable` in `default.nix`, but it doesn't work.

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "dev";
  dontUnpack = true;
  buildInputs = [ nodejs-17_x ];
  postPhases = ''
    corepack enable
  '';
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75687142/19065591 this answer helped me fix same problem

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else who ends up here via a search engine :)

```
corepack enable

corepack prepare yarn@3.2.2 --activate
```

(`enable` is needed to install the symlinks, and prepare + activate sets the correct version.)

This should work on v16.9.0+ (and even v14.19.0+)

source: https://nodejs.org/api/corepack.html#upgrading-the-global-versions