# Not able to install Yarn through corepack

Tags: nvm, yarnpkg-v3, corepack

Environment: Windows, Node 16.18.0, Corepack 0.14.1

I am following [these instructions](https://next.yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install) to install Yarn.

When I run `corepack prepare yarn@3.2.4` or `corepack prepare yarn@3.2.4 --activate`

I get the following error:

```
Preparing yarn@3.2.4... Internal Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\rashiditaba\AppData\Local\node\corepack\yarn\3.2.4' Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\node\corepack\yarn\3.2.4'
```

Comment: Could you please post the directory where corepack is installed.

Answer (score 22):

Hello I experienced the same problem. Corepack is an experimental tool to help with managing versions of your package managers. Due to its experimental status, Corepack currently needs to be explicitly enabled to have any effect.

Disable Corepack with the command:

> corepack disable

You will now be able to install yarn via npm:

> npm install -g yarn --force

To check the installed version of yarn use:

> yarn -v

To upgrade the version use (stable version 3.2.4):

> yarn set version stable

Now you can enable corepack again (if it fails keep it disabled):

> corepack enable

Try the failed command:

> corepack prepare yarn@3.2.4 --activate

I leave you the link with the description of the solution:
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/corepack.html

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. There seems to be a problem which prevents corepack from downloading the latest yarn.js script file.

My solution:

- run `corepack enable` as described in the install guide
- create the folder `AppData\Local\node\corepack\yarn\3.4.1`
- download `https://repo.yarnpkg.com/3.4.1/packages/yarnpkg-cli/bin/yarn.js` and place the file in the folder you just created
- run `corepack prepare yarn@stable --activate`

and you should be good to go:

```
> yarn -v
3.4.1
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error your getting it seems like you have to wrong directory PATH to yarn. Find the directory where yarn is installed and update it's PATH in the environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and discovered that the yarn.js file was being downloaded, but not into the expected location.

The yarn.js file was downloaded to a new folder created with the path `C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\node\corepack\corepack-NEW_RANDOM_NAME`
I just moved this folder into the yarn directory and renamed it to match the expected path `C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\node\corepack\yarn\4.0.0`

Then I reran the `corepack prepare yarn@stable --activate` command and now yarn is reporting that it is version 4.0.0